# Javascript Update Attribute

Tags: javascript, xcode, html, attributes

```
   <input type="text" name="araButon" onKeyUp="return arama()" class="form-control filter" data-filter="app" id="focusedInput"/>
```

I want to update 'data-filter' value by javascript 
I tried this code :

> var gelenText = document.getElementById("focusedInput");
>         document.getElementById("focusedInput").getAttribute("data-filter")=gelenText.value;

Can someone help me?

Comment: gelenText is an element and not a string according to your code. You need to get that element's value and then it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) or [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/element/setAttribute),

```js
// dataset
document.getElementById('focusedInput').dataset.filter = "test";

// setAttribute
document.getElementById('focusedInput').setAttribute('data-filter', 'test-1');
```

```html
<input type="text" name="araButon" onKeyUp="return arama()" class="form-control filter" data-filter="app" id="focusedInput" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do:

```
var focusedInput = document.getElementById("focusedInput");
var dataFilter = focusedInput.getAttribute("data-filter");
focusedInput.value = dataFilter;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ha6jy2L9/1/